# Specific VB Excel Color Dialog

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking for a very specific Color Dialog box in Excel the last couple hours, but all examples I've found aren't exactly the same.  I'm looking for this Color Dialog box to incorporate into a form.

I'm not too familiar with Dialogs either...  any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the windows common dialog (add additional controls to form....Microsoft Common Dialog.  drop it onto form).  These links should help you to get started.

http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1762

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646375(VS.85).aspx

here is a very quick example:

```
Sub OpenForm()

Dim colorSelector As CommonDialog

Set colorSelector = New CommonDialog
    colorSelector.ShowColor 'opens the dialog as

MsgBox colorSelector.Color 'show result as long

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to load the form from the first link, 

The form class contained in '...' is not supported in VBE.  The file can't be loaded.

It doesn't seem to recognize the CommonDialog object as well...  any ideas?  I'm running VB6